Как добавить progress bar в телеграмм боте
У меня есть телеграмм бот, который по запросу пользователя высылает ему на почту файл с нужными данными. Как сделать так, чтобы во время того, как файл подготавливается и отправляется у пользователя в чате высвечивался progress bar, который бы показывал, что код не забагался и сколько времени осталось ждать
Пока что есть такой вариант, сам progress bar отправляется, но не происходит его заполнение
chat_id = update.effective_chat.id
    for _ in tg_tqdm(range(1), os.getenv('TELEGRAM_TOKEN'), chat_id):
        get_need_file(update, context)
        time.sleep(10)


отправляешь сообщение с пустым прогресс баром, запоминаешь его id и обновляешь его когда нужно заполняя бар по чуть-чуть

@dofi4ka подскажите, пожалуйста, как отправить сообщение с пустым прогресс баром?

ну что вы понимаете под пустым прогресс баром то и отправляйте. Можете отправить сообщение с текстом "progress [                    ] (0%)" и сохраняете его id где-нибудь, потом увидели что 20% работы завершено то редактируете сообщение и вставляете текст "progress [####                ] (20%)"


Отправляешь сообщение с 0 прогрессом.
По мере готовности меняешь сообщение через редактирование.
Когда файл готов, удаляешь старое сообщение и присылаешь новое, что файл готов (не через правку - для того, чтобы уведомление пришло).


подскажите, пожалуйста, как отправить сообщение с 0 прогрессом? не могу найти правильный функционал

@ЕленаСергеева, как угодно.

Нас всегда обманывали
https://habr.com/ru/news/745322/
Например так



Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — из очереди проверок

@Dev18, почему не является?

@Qwertiy, Потому что приложена статья (без какого-либо решения, а лишь полемика, что прогрессбары могут быть фейковыми и не привязаны к событиям, как говорит Рами...). и гифка. Я не вижу ответа.

@Dev18, ответ заключается в том, чтобы послать такую бесконечную гифку.

@Qwertiy, Это больше похоже на комментарий или абстрактную идею, а не полноценный ответ.
